# how can i get mysqsl percentages exactly 100%

Tags: mysql, database, procedure

i have query that calculate percentages

```
select a.sp_name, 
       a.sale_date,
       b.sale_amt,
       sum(range1),
       CONCAT(ROUND((SUM((range1 / b.sale_amt)) * 100),2),'%') as ran1per,
       sum(range2),
       CONCAT(ROUND((SUM((range2 / b.sale_amt)) * 100),2),'%') as ran2per,
       sum(range3),
       CONCAT(ROUND((SUM((range3 / b.sale_amt)) * 100),2),'%') as ran3per
from (
    select sp_name, 
           sp_code,
           sale_date,    
           SUM(CASE WHEN code BETWEEN '000000' AND '000100' THEN sale_amt ELSE 0 END) as range1,    
           SUM(CASE WHEN code BETWEEN '000101' AND '000200' THEN sale_amt ELSE 0 END) as range2,    
           SUM(CASE WHEN code BETWEEN '000201' AND '000999' THEN sale_amt ELSE 0 END) as range3
           from sales_detail 
           group by sale_date
    ) as a join sales as b on a.sp_code = b.sp_code
```

but sometimes this query exceed 100% or under 100%
so i need to revise this query,how can i solve this problem?
i'm not dba so please tell me the details
to be exactly 100%

Comment: Your query is incorrect. Outer query uses implicit but incomplete GROUP BY

Comment: *sometimes this query exceed 100% or under 100% so i need to revise this query* The query revision won't help. This is common rounding problem. Adjust the values on the client side. You round till 2 decimals, so the deviation may be +/- 0.01. You must detect the direction and add/substract this deviation from the greatest value accordingly.

Comment: i know this query need to revise
but i don't know how can
so if you know tell me how can i do this..